# How do I use events with ComboBoxes that have variables in their names?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a Userform that will dynamically create ComboBoxes based on a number that the user enters on a previous page (`numofSku`). I populated the contents of the first set of ComboBoxes (`skubox`) from an Access database, and I'd like to populate the second set (`asst`) based on the values of the first set. Naturally, you'd use something like `ComboBox1_Change()` but I'm not sure how to do this with a dynamic set of ComboBoxes.

Code that I use to create the comboboxes:

```
Dim cCntrl As Control
Dim eCntrl As Control
Dim fCntrl As Control
Dim gCntrl As Control
Dim hCntrl As Control
Dim iCntrl As Control
For d = 1 To numofSku
    Set cCntrl = Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "", True)
    Set eCntrl = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "", True)
    Set fCntrl = Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "", True)
    Set gCntrl = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "", True)
    Set hCntrl = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "", True)
    Set iCntrl = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "", True)
    With cCntrl
        .Name = "skubox" & d
        .Width = 90
        .Height = 18
        .top = 5 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 60
    End With
    With eCntrl
        .Caption = "SKU " & d & ":"
        .Width = 35
        .Height = 25
        .top = 5 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 25
    End With
    With fCntrl
        .Name = "asst" & d
        .Width = 45
        .Height = 18
        .top = 5 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 190
    End With
    With gCntrl
        .Caption = "ASST: "
        .Width = 30
        .Height = 25
        .top = 5 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 160
    End With
    With hCntrl
        .Name = "qty" & d
        .Width = 45
        .Height = 18
        .top = 5 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 280
    End With
    With iCntrl
        .Caption = "QTY: "
        .Width = 30
        .Height = 25
        .top = 5 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 250
    End With
Next d
```

Code that I use to fill the first set of comboboxes:

```
For e = 1 To numofSku
    rst.Open "SELECT MasterSKU FROM Brand WHERE Brand = " & "'" & getBrand & "'"
    rst.MoveFirst
    With Me.Controls("skubox" & e)
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rst![MasterSKU]
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
    rst.Close
Next e
```

Comment: You're creating Excel-Forms controls, but expecting them to expose MSForms control events.

Comment: So an event like that isn't compatible with these controls?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Form controls are attached to a macro, period. ActiveX controls have event handlers.

Comment: Cant you just right click on the Form control and assign a macro to it?

Comment: Would it be possible, then, to have the user manually input an assortment (changing the `asst` combobox to a textbox) and then validate that by comparing it to the available options in the database?

Comment: You can probably set their `OnAction` property to assign a macro to them dynamically

Comment: I think I actually like this more than the suggestion that I merely create a bunch of controls and hide them if they're unnecessary. Could I create a macro that passes an argument? I'm thinking I can pass the `d` value into the macro and then within the macro I can populate the `asst` combobox by referencing the value stored in the `skubox` combobox.

Comment: Follow up question: when I create an `.OnAction` argument and I pass a variable into it, does it use the value of the variable when the control was created or is the value passed to the macro whatever the variable is holding at the time the `.OnAction` is triggered? (i.e. if `d = 2` then I have `skubox2`; would the `.OnAction` pass 2 or would it pass `d`'s final value?)

Comment: And I'm just thinking out loud here, but if the `d` value isn't preserved with each instance of the combobox created, then I'd need to create another variable in order to store the number to pass into the `.OnAction` argument. Would it be possible to dynamically create variables in vba? Would I be able to store the information as a part of the control itself as some sort of index number?

Comment: I think you're over-thinking this. Step through your code and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: "you cannot create controls dynamically at runtime in Access!".

You can do it in design view. This is helpful for wizards.

The long answer: My approach to this problem is to put a lot of controls on the form in advance and to set their `Visible` property to `False`. Then, at runtime, you can dynamically make the controls you need visible.

---

Also, consider using a sub-form. In Access, you can insert a `Form` into another `Form` as if it was a `Control`. In fact, Access inserts a Subform-Control displaying the form.

Display this subform either as `Datasheet` or as `Continuous Forms` by setting its `Default View` property accordingly. The Datasheet view looks like a table, whereas the Continuous Forms view displays one copy of the subform per data record.